# How to enable SSL for Oracle connections in JDBC from Rails?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, oracle, ssl, jdbc

I have a Rails application (running on JRuby) that is connecting to an Oracle database, my `database.yml` looks something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: jdbc
  username: ...
  password: ...
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

development:
  <<: *default
  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1526
```

As far as I'm aware, Oracle supports using TLS to connect to a database, how do I enable that in my `database.yml`?

Comment: What about adding `-Doracle.net.tns_admin=..` and `-Doracle.net.wallet_location=..`  ? Then you can use tnsnames.ora to configure everything.

Comment: Check out the SSL for Oracle Connecitons whitepaper.  www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/wp-oracle-jdbc-thin-ssl-130128.pdf